# RecyclerView showing only first two items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to parse a remote JSON file, everything works fine but it only shows first two items and nothing else.

I checked XML file and height of the layout is `wrap_content`.

Here is my code in fragment where I am trying to use `RecyclerView`.

```
        channel_list = view.findViewById(R.id.channel_list);
    channel_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
    channel_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    channel_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    channel_adapter = new Channel_Adapter(listItems,getActivity());
    channel_list.setAdapter(channel_adapter);

    channel_progress = view.findViewById(R.id.channel_progress);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            channel_data,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    channel_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("channels");

                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Channel_Item item = new Channel_Item(
                                    o.optString("name"),
                                    o.optString("network"),
                                    o.optString("description"),
                                    o.optString("programs"),
                                    o.optString("logo")
                            );

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Size" + listItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        channel_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            channel_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Here is the XML file for the same.

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<FrameLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/channel_progress"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/channel_list">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

here is my whole logcat

```
03-24 18:09:14.247 4845-4845/a.tvreminder I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
03-24 18:09:14.355 4845-4845/a.tvreminder W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-24 18:09:14.791 4845-4871/a.tvreminder D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default

                                                               [ 03-24 18:09:14.942  4845: 4869 D/         ]
                                                               HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa94665c0, tid 4869
03-24 18:09:14.944 4845-4869/a.tvreminder I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-24 18:09:14.944 4845-4869/a.tvreminder D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
03-24 18:09:14.944 4845-4869/a.tvreminder W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
03-24 18:09:14.945 4845-4869/a.tvreminder D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
03-24 18:09:15.037 4845-4845/a.tvreminder W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
```

here is my adapter.

```
public class Channel_Adapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<Channel_Adapter.ViewHolder> {

View v;

private List<Channel_Item> listItems;
private Context context;

public Channel_Adapter(List<Channel_Item> listItems, Context context) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Channel_Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.channel_card, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Channel_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Channel_Item item = listItems.get(position);

    holder.channel_name.setText(item.getName());
    holder.channel_network.setText(item.getNetwork());
    holder.channel_description.setText(item.getDescription());

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(item.getLogo())
            //.thumbnail(0.9f)
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image)
            .into(holder.channel_logo);


    holder.card_body.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            item.getPrograms();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView channel_name,channel_network,channel_description;
    public ImageView channel_logo;
    public LinearLayout card_body;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        channel_network = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_network);
        channel_description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_description);
        channel_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_name);
        channel_logo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_logo);
        card_body = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_card_body);

    }
}

public void updateChannelList(List<Channel_Item> channelList){
    this.listItems.addAll(channelList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Comment: could you show us your adapter?

Comment: and how do you pass the items to the RecyrcleVIew?

Comment: if you are adding list empty first time and calling API and notifying the adapter then you have to change it, take another list and add data in the volley and this list should be addAll by the main list.

Comment: actualy i dnot see the you are passing the new items to your RecyclerAdapter

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque I just added the adapter code

Comment: Can you please show the whole code in your activity/fragment responsible for the recyclerView. including declaration, initialization and everything.

Comment: @Chirag I just edited the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it, I found a solution but I don't exactly know how and why it works. But I think your recyclerView was already working fine and was loading all the items.

Step 1:- Remove the ScrollView in your XML and keep only FrameLayout and it's contents (i.e progressbar and recyclerview)

Step 2:- set `channel_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);`

I hope that does the job.

Comment: Thanks, It worked.. It would have been great if we knew how and why this worked.

Comment: hi, i used xml design like this. couse i dont want to scroll recyclerview without scrollview. if i do your solution ,first scroll recyclerview end of recyclerview item after then scroll scrollview. how can i do ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify the `layout_height` of ScrollView, FrameLayout, RecyclerView to `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

add a public method in your channel_adapter to update the list

```
public void updateChannelList(List<Channel_Item> channelList){
            this.channelList.addAll(channelList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and then clear the `listItems` to refresh the list

```
try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("channels");

                        listItems.clear();
                        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Channel_Item item = new Channel_Item(
                                    o.optString("name"),
                                    o.optString("network"),
                                    o.optString("description"),
                                    o.optString("programs"),
                                    o.optString("logo")
                            );

                            listItems.add(item);
                        }



                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Size" + listItems.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        channel_adapter.updateChannelList(listItems);


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I am unable to call `channel_adapter.updateChannelList(listItems);`

Comment: please update your `activity` class where you are trying to access `updateChannelList`

Comment: the only reason i see is that you may be some typo while calling `updateChannelList` from activity as calling the particular method has public visibility. so public method of classes are accessible outside the class.

Comment: I am calling the method from a fragment, does that make a difference?

Comment: Also, I checked the spellings etc, I don't find any error there.